# Plot combinations of values from multiple columns (ggplot2 with R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I have the following toy dataframe in R and am attempting to plot the number of True-True, False-True, True-False, and False-False combinations from columns B and C. These True and False values also correspond to 2 conditions ("X" or "Y").

```
A       B       C
X       True    True
Y       False   True
X       False   False
Y       True    True
Y       True    False
...     ...
```

I'm new to ggplot, so the below code is clearly wrong since I'm currently only plotting column B. I'd highly appreciate advice about how to adapt this to what I need to properly visualize my data! Many thanks.

```
plot = data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, fill = B)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'count')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply set fill to `interaction(B,C)`.

```
plot = data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, fill = interaction(B,C))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'count')
```